# How to find unicode characters represented via \string command

Tags: pdftex, pdf, unicode, metadata, token-lists

I'm using PDFLaTex compiler and want to produce PDF/A-1b format file. I'm using the package `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

I'm having problem with the unicode encoding for PDF meta-data. I want to use unicode in the Author meta-data, e.g.:

```
\pdfinfo{%
    /Author   (š)
}
```

This produces the following value for the Author meta-data in PDF document, instead of the value `š`:

```
unhbox voidb@x group let unhbox voidb@x setbox @tempboxa hbox {sglobal mathchardef accent@spacefactor spacefactor }accent 20 segroup spacefactor accent@spacefactor
```

So I tried to find a way to encode some of the unicode characters that I need, so that they will be displayed properly in PDF document.

I found an approach with the Tex tokens, i.e. for `Š` I can use `\string\227`. Through brute force I have found a code correspondence for some unicode letters that I need:

```
227:Š
231:Ž
235:š
236:ž
```

But I can't find the codes for letter `č` and `Č`. Is there any easier way, like a lookup table, for this? Or any other approach to make it work in this specific case that I described?

Comment: yes, but you should really try to give more details about where you need the letters, and how you input them and you actually compile.

Comment: I said where - I want them in the PDF meta-data. I added the used compiler.

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to ask for all needed info  one by one. Provide a complete example and more info or wait for someone else.

Comment: I updated and described the question with all of the details.

Comment: if you use the \pdfinfo primitive you should check the PDF reference for the syntax and encoding in strings. It would be easier to let hyperref do the work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use package `hyperref` it takes care of the encoding for the PDF information entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={š},
}
\begin{document}
  Hello World
\end{document}
```

The (truncated) output of `pdfinfo`:

```
Author:         š
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.21
```

Option setting `pdfencoding=auto` creates a Unicode string first, but uses the simpler 8-bit PDFDocEncoding if all characters in the string can be reencoded.
(In this case, `š` can be indeed encoded in the latter encoding).

Of course, the strings can also be manually specified in `\pdfinfo`:

```
% Unicode (UTF-16BE with BOM)
\pdfinfo{/Author (\string\376\string\377\string\001\string\141)}% string with octal escapes
\pdfinfo{/Author <feff0161>}% hexadecimal string

% PDFDocEncoding
\pdfinfo{/Author (\string\235)}
\pdfinfo{/Author <9d>}
```

The PDF reference (PDF 1.7/ISO 32000-1:2008) only supports the two encodings PDFDocEncoding (1-byte/8-bit, similar to ISO-8859-1, but with some differences) and UTF-16BE with BOM (multi-byte) for information and bookmark strings. UTF-8 cannot be used directly.

Package `hyperref` takes care of the encoding stuff and supports quite some TeX stuff (but far from all) in information and bookmark strings and saves the user from the manual cumbersome way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}

^^^^0160 %Š
^^^^0161 %š
^^^^017d %Ž
^^^^017e %ž
^^^^010c %Č
^^^^010d %č

\end{document}
```

Any more you need, just google Character + Unicode. The tables can be found in numerous places.

Comment: as the OP uses pdflatex this is probably not what is needed.

Comment: This produces the error `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ^^^ (U+001E (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX`